# VBA(excel) Regex matche , replace and divid (newbe)

Tags: regex, excel, vba

Off that bat let me say im real new to VBA(Excel) :D

Anyway i have an input of
Vigil, RR# FM3434 , Vigil

I need the input(from cell) divided into

RR# FM3434

F

M

3434

and put all 4 parts into there own variable so i can play with them. RR# is the only thing that well stay the same the F and M along with the numbers well change and numbers can be longer but well stop with a space or ,

so would be find

RR# LM5464

place in a variable then remove "RR# " then remove the numbers placing them in a variable and then divid the L and M and place both of them into there own variable

And if its not tell hard plz leave notes on the coding giving some info on what is going on :D as always ty for any help any of you can give me

Comment: Suggest you add your answer below, which shows the code you have tried, to your question, to keep it from being closed

Comment: Where i added the code was not the right place ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are on the right track with a regex, but I would suggest a single regex, and then just pull out the parts using Submatches.  For example:

```
Option Explicit
Function SDI(S As String)
    Dim RE As Object, allMatches As Object, SM As Object
    Const sPat As String = "\b(RR#)\s+([A-Z])([A-Z])(\d+)"
    Dim vResult(0 To 3) As Variant
    Dim I As Long

Set RE = CreateObject("vbscript.regexp")
With RE
    .Global = True
    .IgnoreCase = True  'or false, depending on your requirements
    .Pattern = sPat
    If .test(S) = True Then
        Set allMatches = RE.Execute(S)
        Set SM = allMatches(0).submatches
        For I = 0 To SM.Count - 1
            vResult(I) = SM(I)
        Next I
    End If
End With

MsgBox Join(vResult, ".....")

End Function
```

Comment: that does the trick and it look like you just showed me how to make an array what is something i been trying to figure out for some time now :D

Answer (score 0):

this is the best i could come up with lol

```
Sub ExtractSDI()
Dim text As String
Dim result As String
Dim allMatches As Object
Dim RE As Object
Set RE = CreateObject("vbscript.regexp")

text = "RR# FM454"

RE.Pattern = "(RR# [a-z]{2}\d+)"
RE.Global = True
RE.IgnoreCase = True
Set allMatches = RE.Execute(text)

If allMatches.Count <> 0 Then
'full name
    result = allMatches.Item(0).SubMatches.Item(0)

    'remove the RR#
    text = result
    RE.Pattern = "([a-z]{2}\d+)"
    Set allMatches = RE.Execute(text)
    result2 = allMatches.Item(0).SubMatches.Item(0)

    ' Keep only numbers
    text = result2
    RE.Pattern = "(\d+)"
    Set allMatches = RE.Execute(text)
    result3 = allMatches.Item(0).SubMatches.Item(0)

    ' Gives me the FM
    text = result2
    RE.Pattern = "([a-z]{2})"
    Set allMatches = RE.Execute(text)
    result4 = allMatches.Item(0).SubMatches.Item(0)
    ' Gives me the F
    text = result4
    RE.Pattern = "([a-z]{1})"
    Set allMatches = RE.Execute(text)
    result5 = allMatches.Item(0).SubMatches.Item(0)

    ' Gives me M
    result6 = Replace(result4, result5, "")

End If


MsgBox (result & "....." & result2 & ".........." & result3 & "....." & result4 & "..." & result5 & "....." & result6)
End Sub
```